# Best way to merge multiple columns for pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, merge, concatenation

I'd like to merge/concatenate multiple dataframe together; basically it's too add up many feature columns together based on the same first column 'Name'.

```
F1.merge(F2, on='Name', how='outer').merge(F3, on='Name', how='outer').merge(F4,on='Name', how='outer')...
```

I tried the code above, it's working. But I've got say, 100 features to add up together, I'm wondering is there any better way?

Comment: Maybe also works `pd.concat([x.set_index('Name') for x in [df1,df2,df3], ignore_index=True])`

Answer (score 2):

Without data it is not easy, but this can works:

```
df = pd.concat([x.set_index('Name') for x in [df1,df2,df3]]).reset_index()
```

Comment: I tired to concatenate 30 of them, and found produce all NaN, any ideas? Thanks